# How do I disable a secondary tooltip on a highcharts graph?

Tags: highcharts

Right now when I use highcharts, when I hover over a datapoint it displays the title. Anyone know how to get rid of this? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bBaW.jpg This is what it looks like, I'm trying to get rid of the bottom box.

Comment: You can customize your tooltip using tooltip key of the highcharts config.
I have shared an example from its docs.
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

Comment: That customizes the wrong tooltip, the tooltip key modifies the top tooltip, not the bottom one. Notice how one says 100% and another says 0% I want to get rid of the 0%

Comment: I believe you are showing 2 data in tooltip. If you can share your code I may able to help

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tooltip like that:

```
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/khxc6ygv/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled

Comment: That disables the wrong tooltip, I don't want the top tooltip to be disabled, I want the bottom one that shows 0%